# Getting Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout error in httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty

I have used `httparty` gem in rails 4 app

while I am posting to an api the query is running in the server, but my console breaks with the error `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`.

FYI: I am posting the data to create a record in different site with this api. The record is getting saved each time on its way, but in half way i am getting the error.

This is my code to connect api

```
response =  HTTParty.post(create_account_url, 

    :query => {"customer"=>{"last_name"=>"das",
     "password_confirmation"=>"password",
     "password"=>"password",
     "first_name"=>"asd",
    "email"=>"myemail@email.com"}})
```

Please help me to fix this out.

ALso I have used `default_timeout 120` it gives me the same issue

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? I'm getting a very suspicious  `Net::ReadTimeout` myself, and this is the most related question on SO.

Comment: @asfallows : I have not get any answer to this question.. But somehow I have rescued this error. It was just disconnecting from the server after some seconds. I just added some rescue and sleep for 10 seconds and again restart connecting to the api if Net::ReadTimeout error happens, it resolved my issue. Hope you will try anything like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having has to do with timeout being set in milliseconds, causing there to be a timeout after only 120ms, which may be an unreasonable response time for many servers.

Comment: Do you mean timeout or open_timeout?